# How to know from which parent component an event occured

Tags: reactjs

in a "book" component i have this:

```
<select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onShelfChange}>
                <option>Currently Reading</option>
                <option>Want to Read</option>
                <option>Read</option>
                <option>None</option>
</select>
```

the onChange triggers this function (in the same component)

```
onShelfChange(e){
    //get the newShelf from the 'select'
    let newShelf = e.target.value


    if(newShelf==="Want to Read"){
      newShelf = "wantToRead"
       }
    else if(newShelf==="Read"){
      newShelf = "read"
            }
    else if(newShelf==="Currently Reading"){
      newShelf = "currentlyReading"
            }

    //get the bookID passed from parent component
    const bookID = this.props.bookID

    console.log(bookID)
    console.log(newShelf)

    //call the function that was passed as prop
    this.props.onShelfUpdate(bookID, newShelf)
  }:
```

the prop.onShelfUpdate is given by parent 1. And i want to be able to call another onShelfUptade that is in parent 2. For this i need to know from WHICH one of both parents the change on the shelf was made, so to do something like:

```
    if (it comes from parent 1){
this.props.onShelfUpdateParent1
    }
else if (it comes from parent 2){
this.props.onShelfUpdateParent2
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use by callback, for example:

your render

```
<select value={this.props.value} onChange={(e) => this.onShelfChange(e, this.props.callback)}>
  <option>Currently Reading</option>
  <option>Want to Read</option>
  <option>Read</option>
  <option>None</option>
</select>
```

Your handling

```
onShelfChange(e, callback) {
  //get the newShelf from the 'select'
  let newShelf = e.target.value

  if(newShelf==="Want to Read"){
    newShelf = "wantToRead"
  }
  else if(newShelf==="Read"){
    newShelf = "read"
  }
  else if(newShelf==="Currently Reading"){
    newShelf = "currentlyReading"
  }

  //get the bookID passed from parent component
  const bookID = this.props.bookID

  console.log(bookID)
  console.log(newShelf)

  //call the function that was passed as prop
  // this.props.onShelfUpdate(bookID, newShelf)
  // callback for dynamic function
  callback(bookID, newShelf)
}
```

suppose your render select call by `Dropdown`. so you can pass by parent like this:

```
<Dropdownn callback={this.handleUpdateByParentApp} />
```

or from parent 2

```
<Dropdownn callback={this.handleUpdateByParent2App} />
```

remmeber, you have to set 2 params, cause you call with 2 params.

Comment: Actually the only thing i needed to do was to give the same name to the props given by both parents (in your answer: "callback")! Then i guess it automatically knows where it comes from ;)